# Suggestions on adding a comments section to my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, comments

I want to add a comments section to my iPhone app and i wondered if anyone have any ideas of how to that?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I'm sorry it was my first time asking.. I rephrased myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214858/suggestions-on-adding-a-comments-sectionnot-feedback-to-my-iphone-app)

Comment: There's not nearly enough info here to give a good answer.  Tell us more about your app, and we can give you better advice.

Comment: please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214858/suggestions-on-adding-a-comments-sectionnot-feedback-to-my-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're wanting to give your users a way of writing comments about your apps, for you to receive feedback. One good way to do this is by allowing to user to compose an email which is addressed to you. Use a FMailComposeViewController to present the email interface. 
Include the MessageUI.framework in your project.
Declare your view controller to be a MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.
Then when you want the message view to appear:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *myMailViewCon = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[myMailViewCon setMailComposeDelegate:self];
//set it's contents
[myMailViewCon setSubject:@"app feedback"];
[myMailViewCon setToRecipients:@"yourAddress@email.com"];
[myMailViewCon setMessageBody:@"Dear app developer, here are my comments:"] isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:myMailViewCon animated:YES];
[myMailViewCon release];
```

Comment: thank you for your descriptive answer.