# Suggestions on adding a comments section(not feedback) to my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sharing

My app is about sharing content and i want to give users the ability to share their comments about the content in the app... not a review or feedback to me but for sharing with other users.

I'm not sure on the exact word for it but I mean something like a talkback or a wallpost or a response like there is an option leave a comment here in stack overflow.

Anyway my question is if anyone knows of a way to do that?
I thought about using the Facebook graph api but never seen something like this before.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
found a great blog about [disqus platform](http://appworks.radeeccles.com/programming/disqus-api-objective-c/) that shows how to add a comment section to an app using the [disqus platform](http://player.vimeo.com/video/15268739?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=ffffff&loop=1)
thanks to superjessi for the idea..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestions on adding a comments section to my iPhone app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7211267/suggestions-on-adding-a-comments-section-to-my-iphone-app)

Comment: It is sort of a duplicate.. I wrote the last question too yet i haven't made my myself as clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the Disqus API.  They're widely used for a commenting system and don't require users to make a new account, Disqus accounts work anywhere Disqus is used.  I have seen other apps use it, and it seems to work beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

What prevents you from storing those comments in your own database? Then you just have to design a standard UIView to enter the comments and show the comments in a WebView or an UIView.

Comment: I don't wish to reinvent the wheel and I asked if anyone had already invented it and shared it..

Comment: Then you should have asked for a library. Anyway, you got what you wanted, so good luck using it :D